# How do I get user activity data from the Google API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I want to retrieve user activity data using the Google Analytics Reporting API. I code in PHP (not that it's relevant to this question)

I am following instructions from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting

I am using the _ga client ID cookie stored in browser for the "userId", but I get the following response:

`{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "service": "analyticsreporting.googleapis.com", "method": "google.analytics.reporting.v4.Reporting.SearchUserActivity" } } ] } }`

This seems like I have to let the user sign into Google before I can get the desired data.

Is it possible to get this data from just the _ga cookie ID, without the user signing in?

Below is the request from the client. They say I need to use the Google Reporting API. This also seems like it can only work once signed in?

1. When a lead is submitted using the contact form, capture the Google Analytics ClientID (stored in the _ga cookie in the browser) as part of the submission.
2. Using the ClientID, interrogate the Google Analytics Reporting API for the "first interaction" (first session) user activity linked to this lead, fetching the data linked to the following variables:

- Source
- Medium
- Campaign Name
- Campaign Content
- Campaign Term
- Search Query

3. Once the data has been retrieved from the GA API (which can sometimes take up to 15 minutes to populate in the GA databases), pass the full payload, including the lead details and the marketing characteristics through to the CRM.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with User Activity API but generally familiar with coding against Google's services. From what I understand from your question, the user who makes the request **will** need to authenticate to Google to invoke the API's method(s). This is often done with an access token. When you write "the user" I assume you mean the Google Analytics owner. It's unclear how the owner is invoking the method but you'll need to provide a way for them to get an access token to apply to the method for it to work.

Comment: See [Try This Method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search) on the method's documentation page to see how APIs Explorer acquires an access token from a signed in user in order to make the call.

Comment: Thank you for the info @DazWilkin.

I received this request from SEO specialists that works for my client. 

I suppose all the info is pointing to the fact that some authorization needs to take place. I will do more research on my end.